# Metric properties of graphs of lie groups homomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-homomorphism

graphs of homomorphism of $(\mathbb{R}^{n},+)$ are minimal submanifolds.
The same holds for ($S^{1},\times$).
Are there generalizations of these statements?

Comment: Arguably the notion of coupling/joining is among the broadest generalizations; by way of the measure rigidity paradigm. (E.g. in your examples it suffices to consider measurable group homomorphisms)

Comment: Already the first sentence is wrong: While linear subspaces are minimal in the Euclidean space, there are many other minimal submanifolds.

Comment: That's also false once the dimension is high enough (say, when you are considering homomorphisms from $R^2$ to itself), even if you allow translates of graphs of homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a Lie group equipped with a biinvariant semi-Riemannian metric. (For instance, take any compact Lie group with a biinvariant Riemannian metric.) Then nonconstant geodesics in $G$ are $G$-translates of 1-parameter subgroups of $G$. Accordingly, Lie subgroups of $G$ are totally geodesic. Now take the direct product of two such metrized groups $G\times H$ with the product semi-Riemannian metric. Graphs of continuous homomorphisms $G\to H$ are totally geodesic, hence, minimal, submanifolds of this product.